# what is what is the historical context of the song of the Russian bard, Michael Scherbakov?

Tags: значения

Curious about the historical context of the song of the Russian bard, Michael Scherbakov:

[Михаил Щербаков - Прощальная 2](https://teksty-pesenok.ru/rus-mihail-shherbakov/tekst-pesni-proshhalnaya-2/1855699/)

> Вчера и сегодня, и завтра, и после, почти незаметно, Всегда неизменно,
>   почти не начавшись, кончаются сроки. Суда уплывают, почти не
>   дождавшись попутного ветра. В далёкие дали они уплывают, почти не
>   разведав счастливой дороги. Они исчезают, становятся сказкой,
>   становятся былью, Но долгое время мне видятся в дымке их белые крылья.

Feels like the song is about the end of an era, but I am not sure what period it describes and who is parting from whom.

Perhaps it's about the dissolution of the Soviet Union, that is, how the union of the varios Republics disintegrated, and each became a sovereign state, which resulted in borders rising between people and religions dividing them:

> "нынче меж нами - обряды, обеты, законы, запреты."

But it seems that the people in the song are actually in a process of physically moving away from their friends / loved ones, so perhaps it's about emigration and the the lifting of the iron curtain:

> "Плывите, плывите, и пусть ничего не осталось в залоге. Мы были
>   друзьями, мы стали чужими... Счастливой дороги!"

Whatever the reason, it seems there are no hard feelings between those leaving and those staying behind.

Apologies if lyrics interpretation inquiries are not suitable for this stack.

Comment: what seems certain is that it's not about the USSR dissolution per se because according to the available info the song was released in 1990,  maybe it's a premonition thereof, although it looks pretty generic, emigration seems more plausible, in particular mass Jewish emigration started around that time an intimation to which may be the reference to difference of faith, but poets don't always base their pieces on historical or real events

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Russian language and its usage.